# How to find the prev. class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have no Idea how I can find the prev. class "cmd and path" with jQuery.

Here is my html code:

```
<tr>
    <td>MySQL</td>
    <td class="path">/etc/init.d/mysql</td>
    <td class="cmd">status</td>
    <td><i class="icon-remove"></i> <i class="icon-pencil"></i></td>
</tr>
```

and my jQuery code looks:

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev('.cmd').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest('td').prev('.cmd').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ep9F9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        txtPath = tr.find('.path').text(),
        txtCmd = tr.find('.cmd').text();

});
```

Comment: This is a good answer. You might consider using `.children` instead of `.find`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent(),
        txtCmd = parent.prev('.cmd').text(),
        txtPath = parent.prev('.path').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

THe problem in you code is '.cmd' not prev to your `$(this)`
its prev to `parent`.

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).parent().prev('.cmd').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest('tr').children('.cmd').text(); // .path can also be the selector.
    alert(text);
});
```

Another way is using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).parent().prevAll('.cmd').text(); // .path can also be the selector.
    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

prev() is not working because it's not traversing up the DOM tree, which you need to do for this to work. You need to go up 2 levels, to the tr, and then search the children for the "td" tag with class "cmd". Your code should work like so...

```
$('i.icon-pencil').click(function() {
var text = $(this).parent().parent().children('.cmd').text();
alert(text);
});
```

Hope that helped.